# AChartEgine bar chart is not displayed within ScrollView

Tags: android, achartengine

I've been trying to have my bar chart displayed within a ScrollView but it simply won't work.

This is my layout file, with the "android:fillViewport="true""

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/all"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/subjects"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:text="subjects"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="total"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="certas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:text="erradas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/request"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And this is my code, with the "renderer.setInScroll(true);"

```
XYSeries result = new XYSeries("Respostas");
    result.add(1, correctAnswers);
    result.add(2, wrongAnswers);

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(result);


    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(0);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(0);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(20);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 15, 15, 15, 15 });
    renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00));

    SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
    r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);

    renderer.setChartTitle("");
    renderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(3);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(totalAnswers);
    renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Certas");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "Erradas");
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
    renderer.setXLabels(0);
    renderer.setYLabels(0);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false);
    renderer.setInScroll(true);

    GraphicalView chartView = ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context, dataset, renderer, BarChart.Type.DEFAULT);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.subjects);
    layout.addView(chartView,0);
```

The only way I can make it work is adding this line:

```
chartView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300));
```

But it sucks because the metrics are pixels and yes, I tried MATCH_PARENT but it doesn't work either.

I've seen some questions similiar to mine but none of them has any good answer so I wonder if anybody can help me or if it simply can't be done :(

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the height somewhere. In ScrollView you use wrap_content for heigth. Width is defined by match_parent. The chart is scaled to the height and width of the enclosing container which in your example has no height yet, i.e. height 0. For example you could define the (minimum) height of your chart:

```
chartView.setMinimumHeight(300);
```